# Instantiate function in unity is not spawning objects in desired place

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a simple 2D game in unity where if a ball(prefab) hits the player, a new ball should spawn at 0,0,0. But the ball spawns at random positions in the y-direction

```
public class Ball_collision: MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ball;
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag=="Player")
        {
            Instantiate(ball);
            ball.transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        }
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the position of the prefab `ball`, **NOT** of the newly instantiated object. Rather do e.g.

```
var newBall = Instantiate(ball);
newBall.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
```

If you don't need a reference to the spawned object you could also directly do it with `Instantiate`

```
Instantiate(ball, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.idendity);
```

---

In general rather use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html) instead of `==`. Second silently fails if the tag is e.g. misspelled or non-existent while `CompareTag` throws an error. This makes debugging a lot easier. Besides that it is also slightly faster. ;)

```
if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create new GameObject and then set position of it!

```
    public class Ball_collision: MonoBehaviour
{

        public GameObject ball;
        void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
   

 {
        if(other.gameObject.tag=="Player")
        {
            GameObject newBall = Instantiate(ball);
            newBall.transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
            newBall.gameObject.name = "MyNewBall"; 
            // You can also set new name of this object easier
        }
    }
}
```